# Reading values with dataset messes up specific language characters dependending on client OS

Tags: c#, dataset, dbf, codepages, currentculture

I have made a windows application using C# that creates a dataset with data from a Dbase database file using a OleDBConnection.

My problem is that this runs just fine on my own computer (swedish) but when i run this on my server (english) the swedish letters (å,ä,ö,Å,Ä,Ö) gets messed up.

I have tried this with no luck:

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("sv-SE");
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("sv-SE");
```

Comment: I don't think this problem is with C#, as .Net uses Unicode for all strings. Regional settings also don't affect the character set. I'm going to guess this has something to do with the DB, and suggest you make sure you're using `nvarchar`, `nchar` and `ntext` for all text fields in SQL Server. If the problem is on the DBF side it might be more difficult to fix.

Comment: But when running the application on my own computer (swedish) everything gets done correctly

Comment: Im using a StringBuilder to generate the sql insert query, could this be using the local computers regional setting?

Comment: The thing that affects that is the ANSI codepage (which Windows calls "language for non-Unicode programs" nowadays). It's in the same place in the Control Panel as the regional settings, but it's logically distinct from them. Modifying it requires a reboot, and it's not something you can easily change per-process (except with AppLocale). This setting doesn't affect C# however, since .Net apps are Unicode, not ANSI. It could however affect the DBF database (or potentially SQL Server if you don't use `nvarchar` etc)

Comment: Yeah thats the one that is set to English on the other computer, and i would really not like to change that one unless i really really have to. I tried changing varchar -> nvarchar but it was still the same. Any more ideas?

Comment: I think the problem has already occured with the dataset reading the values from the DBF, so adding to the SQL Server should not be the problem (atleast not the first)

Comment: I'm not an expert on DBF. Perhaps you should edit your question to reflect the actual problem (reading values from DBF returns incorrect results with a different system codepage) and include appropriate tags for DBF, so that someone who knows more about that is more likely to see it (editing your question also moves it back to the top of the list on the homepage).

Answer (score 0):

Ok well so i kinda fixed it myself, not the best of ways but it will work for me.

Since i will be running if on a English OS computer i made function that changed all the weird characters to swedish ones.

```
public string changeSpecialCharacters(string kund)
{
    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder(kund);

    b = b.Replace("σ", "å");
    b = b.Replace("┼", "Å");
    b = b.Replace("Σ", "ä");
    b = b.Replace("─", "Ä");
    b = b.Replace("÷", "ö");
    b = b.Replace("╓", "Ö");

    return b.ToString();
}
```

Until i find a way to do this differently ill stick with it.